# Setting up pyroCMS datebase with mysql

Tags: mysql, pyrocms

I am going through a new pyro install for a project and i am getting stuck on step 2 where i am asked to create a mysql database. Now i have a local mysql DB that i use for projects and to connect to it i usually just need the username "root" and nothing else.

when i try to enter in "localhost" for hostname and "root" for username i expected it to work but i get back "Problem connecting to or creating the database: No such file or directory" If i knew what file or directory it was looking for this would be more easily solved, but i am not sure what it's looking for.

Anyway thanks in advance for any help with this, its nearly 5 am so forgive me if my question sounds a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved the issue. I did not know i couldn't use "localhost" if i wasn't using a socket connection. Instead 127.0.0.1 should be used when setting up your local mysql DB for pyro.